# How do you compile c files with clang into a binary format?

Tags: clang

I created source code as a .c file and tried running `clang exampledebugging.c` into it.

It came up empty.

Can anyone please help me? I am trying to compile this program into a binary executable format.

Comment: What do you mean by "came up empty"? Generally, Linux commands aren't needlessly verbose. Is there now a file named `a.out` in your current directory?

Comment: Ah. Yes. I see it now.

Comment: I guess I didn't need any help after all. Whoopsie :)

Comment: If you want the binary executable to have a different name, you can specify that using `-o` ex. `clang exampledebugging.c -o exampledebugging`. Same thing with `gcc`/`g++`

Comment: I cannot thank for your help. But I ran into one small problem. My gdb debugger won't open :/

Comment: That sounds like it should be a separate question

Comment: I downloaded it from terminal. It said that it has been installed, but I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Never mind I just figure it out haha :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Linux commands aren't needlessly verbose - `clang` doesn't necessarily output anything to the terminal if the command succeeds. In the case of

```
clang exampledebugging.c
```

it should simply have created a binary executable with the default name `a.out` that you can execute using `./a.out`. If you want the output file to be named differently, use the `-o` option:

```
clang exampledebugging.c -o exampledebugging
```

The GNU compilers `gcc` and `g++` behave the same.